# How to resolve MS-Access Macro Error Number 2001?

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, linked-tables

I have a copy of an Access database that is meant for importing discontinued product data from a .csv file into a SQL Server database (by using linked tables). When I initiate this import process, I get the following macro error:

[image]

I looked up the 2001 Error Number and have seen a few different explanations of it. Mainly, that I need to add the location of the database as a trusted location. I have done that, but that hasn't made a difference.

I noticed I can also see what code the problem occurs in, the "ImportDiscontinued()" function which looks like this:

```vb
Public Function ImportDiscontinued()
Dim sImpSpec As String
Dim sImpTable As String
Dim sPath As String
Dim sFile As String
Dim db As Database
Dim rsOption As Recordset
Dim rs As Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rsOption = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT tblOptions.zValue FROM tblOptions WHERE (((tblOptions.zOption)='ImportPath'));")
    sPath = rsOption.Fields("zValue")
Set rsOption = Nothing

If Right(sPath, 1) <> "\" Then
    sPath = sPath & "\"
End If

sImpSpec = "DiscontinuedItemMaster Import Specification"
sImpTable = "tblDiscontinuedCurrent"
sFile = sPath & "DiscontinuedItemMaster.csv"

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.OpenQuery "dqDiscontinuedCurrent"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "dqObsDiscontinuedDuplicates"
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, sImpSpec, sImpTable, sFile, True
DoCmd.OpenQuery "dqDiscontinuedCurrent_Blanks"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "uqObsDiscontinuedCurrent_SameProdRepl"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "uqObsDiscontinuedCurrent_Trim"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "uqObsDiscontinuedCurrent"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "aqObsDiscontinuedDuplicates"
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("dbo_tmpObsDiscontinued_Duplicates")

If rs.EOF Then
    MsgBox "New Discontinued Items Have Imported Successfully! You may now process...", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Success!"
Else
    MsgBox "Duplicates were found!. They will now be removed...", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error"
    DoCmd.RunMacro "mcObsDiscontinuedDuplicates"
End If

Set rsOption = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing

db.Close

End Function
```

But looking at it, I can't really see where things could be going wrong. I noticed I can set breakpoints, but they don't seem to get hit.

I know that the connection to the SQL Server database is OK because I am initially prompted for credentials and then I am able to view the data through the linked table just fine.

A disclaimer that I am only really familiar with the basics of Access so macros and coding in VBA is all new to me. I typically work with SQL Server databases and programming in C#.

EDIT: Here is the macro "mcObsDiscontinuedImport":

[image]

Comment: Error 2001 coukd be caused by [SQL](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a11fc864-b74f-4329-8e79-c74e9a145d98/runtime-error-2001?forum=isvvba) too.Get Rid of`DoCmd.SetWarnings False`and use`db.Execute sql, dbFailOnError`on action queries

Comment: I tried removing `DoCmd.SetWarnings False` and where should `db.Execute sql, dbFailOnError` go? I tried putting it after `Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("dbo_tmpObsDiscontinued_Duplicates")`, still getting the same 2001 error.

Comment: [db.Execite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/database-execute-method-dao) is replacement for`DoCmd.OpenQuery`.

Comment: I just recognized, that the error is caused in the macro`mcObsDiscontinuedDuplicates`where you call`ImportDiscontinued`again. Don'r use macros, as their error handling is poor. To replace the `AutoExec`macro use a hidden form that opens on startup and execute the vba procedure in its open event. Btw, if you are more familiar with c#, why do you use vba? and  it seems like you can [link csv file to sql-server via sp](http://www.enabledbusinesssolutions.com/blogs/adding-csv-files-as-linked-server-connection/).

Comment: I removed the line `DoCmd.RunMacro "mcObsDiscontinuedDuplicates"` but still get the error. I did not create any of this, I have just been tasked with verifying a new SQL Server database that has been created. I was told that another team uses this access database for importing discontinued product data manually and need to make sure it still works when pointing to the new SQL server database. That is the only change I have made, all of the code I pasted above is used in a current production environment on a weekly basis, so I'm thinking the issue is specific to my local environment.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake! Macroname in error msg is`mcObsDiscontinuedImports`, not`mcObsDiscontinuedDuplicates`. So`mcObsDiscontinuedImports`calls your vba code (Action: RunCode, Agrument: ImportDiscontinued()). Any other command in that? Try run`ImportDiscontinued`from vba-ide (F5). Try run each query seperate. Can you do manual import? Other team uses sql-server too? Compare Driver versions, Connections.

Comment: I've updated my post to show the macro, doesn't look like the RunCode section does anything besides call the "ImportDiscontinued()" function. I've tried running in the IDE but it just says "Running" for half a second then disappears even if I set breakpoints, they don't seem to be hit. The other team just uses this access database as a means to put the data into the SQL Server database. I have access to both the current production (old) SQL Server db as well as the new one. The tables have been copied over and should be the same, but I just need to verify that this import process still works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198742/discussion-between-computerversteher-and-reddy).